# How can I change a UITextField position in UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uisearchbar

Is there a way to reposition UITextField inside UISearchBar?
I'd like to move UITextField inside UISearchBar up a little bit.

Comment: I think you have to implement your own search bar.

Answer (score 14):

The UITextField approach is not working anymore, probably due to a restyling of the UISearchBar object. UISearchBar resizes its UITextField when it is presented on screen, this invalidates all manipulations on the UITextField.

However, I discovered that UISearchBar responds to the `setContentInset:` method (tested on iOS 5.0.1). It adjusts the inset distance from the enclosing view.

This result in a sophisticated approach involving NSInvocation:

```
if([aSearchBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setContentInset:)])
{
    SEL aSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"setContentInset:");
    NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[aSearchBar methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector]];

    [inv setSelector:aSelector];
    [inv setTarget:aSearchBar];
    UIEdgeInsets anInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 5, 35);
    [inv setArgument:&anInsets atIndex:2]; //arguments 0 and 1 are self and _cmd respectively, automatically set by NSInvocation
    [inv invoke];
}
```

The above code resizes the `contentInset` of the UISearchBar (effectively UITextField) using the CGRect indicated in the `anInsets` parameter. The parent if-statement (`respondsToSelector:`) saves yourself from changes of this behaviour in new versions of iOS.

**Updated for Swift3 and iOS10:**

```
if searchBar.responds(to: Selector("setContentInset:")) {
   let aSelector = Selector("setContentInset:")
   let anInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 5, 35)
   searchBar.perform(aSelector, with: anInset)
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. For example, to have some space left and right, use the above with:
`UIEdgeInsets anInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 50 /* left */, 5, 50 /* right */);`

Comment: I found that if you leave the top and bottom insets as 0, it applies the default inset. Set as 5, a but happened when I selected the text field that caused it to move up to the top of the searchbar.

Comment: Will this code reject your app from AppStore? Other than that, it does, indeed, work like a charm

Comment: No use of private APIs here and The user interface experience is not changed. So, i think that you can safely submit it to the AppStore.

Comment: This will reject API

Comment: @Saad as far as I know this option is not an issue for the AppStore. Best.

Comment: I am using searchbar in navigation and I want to move only the text to right (say by 50p) . This code moves  the complete search bar. Is there a way to keep the search icon as it is but move the text ?

Comment: @user3752049 Probably too late for an answer but you can do that with property searchTextPositionAdjustment

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4+**

You can try this.

```
searchBar.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 5, vertical: 0)
```

It doesn't move the textField, but moves the text. This should be enough for most people.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is changing of directionalLayoutMargins

```
searchBar.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, leading: 20.0, bottom: 0.0, trailing: 20.0)
```